# I just sent an email in a loop for 5 minutes

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

A bug was in my cron code. I just sent thousands copy of the same email in a loop during 5 minutes to 24 people. All my smtp responses were ok (like Google ones were "gsmtp 201"), meaning that all the emails were received by the servers (but I hope not really delivered).

What will happen ?

I hope that SMTP servers will block them... What do you think ? How do they react to this kind of spam in general ?

Comment: I know this may not be the right place... Could you guys point me towards a more appropriate forum, I'm not really feeling well right now....

Comment: You might be blocked for sending email there in the futur or you hit a RBL list. In all case your reputation will somedays fall ok. If the email were inapripriate, for that we cant do nothing, except maybe sending on your behalf an excuse for the mass spam.

Comment: Btw, I didnt DV, but please know any answer to your question will be speculation, as we don’t know the spam metric of any major hoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://group-mail.com/sending-email/email-send-limits-and-options/

> The Gmail mail server send limit is approximately 100-150 emails per day when connected to the server from a remote email client. You can send 500 emails each day through the Gmail SMTP server when logged into their web interface.

Although that looks promising, I do recommend that you send out an apology email to everyone (even if it was a simple mistake) if people begin to complain. An apology email can go a long way if written well.

Good luck, and hopefully my answer helped and you resolve your issue.

Comment: I've got some feedback. The amount of mails was not so bad, between 60 for one person to 230 for another. Not thousands (well thousands in total, yes). I did send an apology email. Again, I know that maybe this place and this question was not appropriate, but I needed to talk to someone..... Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, no problem and I believe you posted your question in the right place as Cron and SMTP is server fault stuff.